# Prove the following limit translation rule:

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{h \to 0} f(c+h) = L$$

---

My prove for ($\implies$) was:

Let $g(h) = f(c+h)$, then we are required to show that $\lim_{h \to 0} g(h) = L$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Required to show that: $\exists$$\delta >0$, $\forall$$h\in \mathbb{R}$, $0<|h|<\delta$   $\implies$ $|g(h)-L|<\epsilon$

So $\forall$$h$, $|g(h)-L| = |g(h)-f(x)+f(x)-L| \le |g(h)-f(x)| + |f(x)-L|$

I know that I can let $|f(x)-L|$ equal any value that depends on $\epsilon$ since $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$ but I'm not sure what I should do with $|g(h)-f(x)|$. Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$. Set $g(h)=f(c+h)$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $0<|x-c|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Suppose $0<|h|<\delta$. Then
$$
|g(h)-L|=|f(c+h)-L|<\varepsilon
$$
because $0<|(c+h)-c|<\delta$.

Do the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

Let us use sequential characterisation of the limit.

$$\lim_{x\to c}f (x)=L\iff $$

for each sequence $(x_n) $ which converges to $c$, the sequence $(f (x_n )) $ converges to $L $.

now  take a sequence $(h_n ) $ converging to $0$, then $h_n+c \to c $ and $f (h_n+c)\to L $.

conversly, take a sequence $(x_n) $ such that $x_n\to c $, then $x_n-c\to 0$ and
$f (c+x_n-c)\to L $ or $f (x_n)\to L $

Qed.